# Get a list of selected friends without sending messages

Tags: facebook

My online game site uses Facebook as one of authentication backends.

I am using `fb:request-form` to allow a user to invite friends to the site. But if a friend has already joined, instead of a Facebook notification I want to send an in-game message.

Is it possible to get a list of selected userids without sending messages?

Comment: You can't perform multiple actions with a single `fb:request-form`. Your best bet is to filter out friends that have already joined, and make the message a 2nd option. Or you could try deleting the sent requests (I don't remember if this is possible anymore) if they were sent to existing users. Edit: Or you can create your own form/dialog system that does exactly what you want - considerably more work though.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if user exists in your game already. If yes, send him message instead of invitation.

Use powers of AJAX

Comment: I don't receive any callbacks from the Facebook iframe until the messages have been already sent.